# Allowing other threads to print to stdout while using cmdloop from cmd module

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, stdout

I am trying to build an application that uses the cmd module. When I run my program, I want it to drop into the cmdloop and still be able to receive prints from other things. Eventually I will have threads printing from sockets. But I have done some playing around and can't get anything to print while in the cmdloop. It just sits at the prompt ">". But I would still like for it to print out things it receives, or prints our responses from a function if I call one that isn't inside this CLI class.

```
import cmd
import string, sys

class CLI(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = '> '

    def do_hello1(self, arg):
        print "hello1 again", arg, "!"

    def help_hello1(self):
        print "syntax: hello1 [message]",
        print "-- prints a hello1 message"

    def do_quit(self, arg):
        sys.exit(1)

    def help_quit(self):
        print "syntax: quit",
        print "-- terminates the application"

    # shortcuts
    do_q = do_quit


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = ''   
PORT = 5555


try:
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

sock.listen(10)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

cli = CLI()
cli.cmdloop()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
```

Comment: If I run just your `CLI` without the surrounding socket code, it works fine. I can execute the `hello1` command and see the output. When running the above script exactly as it is the CLI never runs because the script blocks waiting for a socket connection at line `sock.accept()`